# I have a vim config. However, when I paste text

Tags: unix, vim

I do "set:paste"

That will allow me to paste text into putty very nicely.

However, my "smart indents" and 'auto tabbing' --which is in my original config..is gone!?

How do I make it so that

1. I don't have to do "set: paste" everytime I want to paste something 
   and
2. if I do have to do that...I can easily go back to normal config?

```
set nohlsearch
set ai
set bg=dark
set showmatch
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=DarkGray
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
syntax on
set listchars=tab:>-
set listchars+=trail:.
set ignorecase
set smartcase
map  :tabr
map  :tabl
map  :tabp
map  :tabn
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to:

```
set pastetoggle=<F6>
```

With this you can change paste status with F6 (you can of course bind it to anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

for 2.
:set nopaste

Comment: or you can toggle using `:set paste!`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use any of the graphical versions of vim (eg gvim, macvim) then they usually have support for copy and paste that doesn't require `:set paste`.

Comment: I usually do "vim filename" . But when I paste it becomes like a pyramid..?

Comment: it sounds like you're using the terminal-based version of vim. you need gvim or macvim to make this work.